# WTForms Validators check field unicity on editing user

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

This is my code:
model:

```
class Employee(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(60), index=True, unique=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(60), index=True, unique=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(60), index=True)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(60), index=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    department_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('departments.id'))
    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('roles.id'))
    is_admin = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
```

my form:

```
class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    """
    Form for users to create new account
    """
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired()])
    first_name = StringField('First Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    last_name = StringField('Last Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[
                                        DataRequired(),
                                        EqualTo('confirm_password')
                                        ])
    confirm_password = PasswordField('Confirm Password')
    submit = SubmitField('Register')

    def validate_email(self, field):
        if Employee.query.filter_by(email=field.data).first():
            raise ValidationError('Email is already in use.')

    def validate_username(self, field):
        if Employee.query.filter_by(username=field.data).first():
            raise ValidationError('Username is already in use.')
```

my route:

```
@auth.route('/register/edit/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def edit_register(id):
    """
    Edit a account
    """
    check_admin()

    add_register = False

    employee = Employee.query.get_or_404(id)
    form = RegistrationForm(obj=Employee)


    del form.password # Ignore password when editing form
    del form.confirm_password


    if form.validate_on_submit():
        employee = Employee(email=form.email.data,
                            username=form.username.data,
                            first_name=form.first_name.data,
                            last_name=form.last_name.data)

        db.session.commit()
        flash('You have successfully edited employee.')

        # redirect to the roles page
        return redirect(url_for('home.dashboard'))

    form.email.data = employee.email
    form.username.data = employee.username
    form.first_name.data = employee.first_name
    form.last_name.data = employee.last_name
return render_template('auth/register.html', action="Edit", add_register=add_register,
                           form=form, title="Edit Employee")
```

the issue is that email and username validators are enabled so I can't edit my user.

Can I add conditions to def validate_email and validate_username to check only on Add user, but if user change its username, I will be a break in my unicity database?
Or could I code something to check it only if user change username or/and email?

avoid validation
thanks

Comment: Why you don't want to create 2 different forms(`RegistrationForm` with required email/username and `UserProfileForm` with non required fields)?

Comment: Yes but the issue is that I will lost validation of unicity..?

Comment: not sure that I understand. can you provide a details? what mean 'lost validation of unicity? server will update employee by 'id'. (`class UserProfileForm: user_id = IntegerField('user_id', validators=[DataRequired()) username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired()]) ...`. and use form with user id and any validators when edit `if request.method == 'POST': form = UserProfileForm(obj=employee) ...`)

Comment: A case : If user want to change his username. If I don t check unicity of username in DB, I could have an error .

Comment: ok. just an [example](https://justpaste.it/5h5v9). what will be wrong?